# Let A and B be sets and let f : A → B be a function. Show that if D ⊆ B, then f(f −1 (D)) ⊆ D.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't even know where to start.

Here are several hints. The goal is to show that if y ∈ f(f
−1
(D)), then y ∈ D. While
notation is meant to serve us, and we should not be servants to notation, and while consistent
use of notation within a body of work is (probably) more important than uniform notation
throughout all of one’s work, we are nonetheless conditioned to think of y as an element of
the co-domain and x as an element of the range. So writing “Suppose x ∈ f(f
−1
(D)). . .”
will probably lead to unhappiness.
Second, this problem does not assume that f is bijective, so the inverse f
−1
need not
exist as a function from B to A.
If the notation is confusing, try putting C = f
−1
(D). Then the goal is to show that
f(C) ⊆ D. What is the definition of C? What is the definition of f(C)?

Comment: if you don't know where to start, go back to definitions.  

1 - definition of subset
2 - definition of f^{-1}(D)

Answer (score 1):

This should help:
For every function $f\colon A\to B$ (whether bijective, injective, surjective, or none of these), we can defined a function $$\begin{align}f^{-1}\colon \mathcal P(B)&\to \mathcal P(A)\\Y&\mapsto \{\,x\in A\mid f(x)\in Y\,\}\end{align}$$ but also $$\begin{align}f\colon \mathcal P(A)&\to \mathcal P(B)\\X&\mapsto \{\,f(x)\mid x\in X\,\}.\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Some things that may help. Say we have a function
$$
F: A \to B
$$
and that $b\in B$ ($b$ is an element of $B$).
Then,
$f^{-1}(b)$ is a set (yes,  a set, I know that can be confusing).

The elements of the set $f^{-1}(b)$ are the elements $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = b$.

If you know set builder notation, then we say that
$$
f^{-1}(b) = \{a\in A: f(a) = b\}
$$
Now, to generalize this, let's say instead of a point in $B$, we have a subset of $B$, call it $D$. Then,
$$
f^{-1}(D) = \{a\in A: f(a)\in D\}
$$

And, similarly, if $C\subset A$, then $f(C)$ is also a set (this time it's $f$ that's used to make a set, not $f^{-1}$). Precisely,
$$
f(C) = \{f(c): c\in C\}
$$

So, if $x\in f(f^{-1}(D))$, we replace $C$ with $f^{-1}(D)$

$$
f(f^{-1}(D)) = \{f(c): c\in f^{-1}(D)\}
$$
This should help you get started. Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Still don't know exactly how I'm supposed to reach the ending from this I have an idea but I'm just so lost, sorry I'm really really dumb